# Private Values on Angular Factory

Tags: angularjs

I have private values on my Factory service, but when I update a private value in  one instance, all instances are updated as well.

Whats the best way to accomplish that without Updating all instances:

---

```
angular.module('app').factory('instanceItem', function () {
  var _valid = true;
  var item = function (id,data){
    this.id = id;
    this.data = data;
  };
  item.prototype.setValid = function(bool) {
    _valid = bool;
  }
  item.prototype.getValid = function() {
    return _valid
  }
  return { item:item }
});
```

What I am getting:

```
var itemA = new instanceItem.item(1,{});
var itemB = new instanceItem.item(2,{});
itemA.setValid(false);
console.log(itemA.getValid());
//False
console.log(itemB.getValid());
//False
```

What I am looking for

```
var itemA = new instanceItem.item(1,{});
var itemB = new instanceItem.item(2,{});
itemA.setValid(false);
console.log(itemA.getValid());
//False
console.log(itemB.getValid());
//True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service is a singleton. So there is a unique instance of _valid. _valid should be a field of item:

```
var item = function (id,data){
    this.id = id;
    this.data = data;
    this._valid = true;
  };
  item.prototype.setValid = function(bool) {
    this._valid = bool;
  }
  item.prototype.getValid = function() {
    return this._valid;
  }
```

Or, if you really want to make it private (and also make your service more natural to use):

```
  function createItem(id, data) {
    var _valid = true;

    return {
      id: id,
      data: data,
      setValid: function(bool) {
        _valid = bool;
      },
      getValid: function() {
        return _valid;
      }
    };
  }
  return { createItem: createItem }
```

Comment: Thanks!! I got it know. Im going with the second approach, the object might get very complicate on the way, and the private methods will be important. Not really sure why Angular choose this aproach for singleton service, when you could use the .prototype to share the the common methods.
Thanks JB.